# Explicit inner product for arbitrary vectors in the tensor product of Hilbert spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products, tensors

Suppose $H_1$ and $H_2$ are Hilbert spaces with respective inner products $\langle \cdot \rangle_1$ and $\langle \cdot \rangle_2$. Take $H = H_1 \otimes H_2$ to be the tensor product of $H_1$ and $H_2$. Then for any basis element
$v_1 \otimes v_2$, and $u_1 \otimes u_2$, we have
$$\langle v_1 \otimes v_2, u_1 \otimes u_2 \rangle = \langle v_1, u_1\rangle_1 \cdot \langle v_2, u_2 \rangle_2.$$

But how do we extend the above to compute inner products involving *any* vector in the tensor product? One obvious way is to expand in terms of basis elements. That is, suppose $a_1 \otimes a_2$ and $b_1 \otimes b_2$ are *not* a basis element of $H$. Thus there exists a a finite linear combination such that
$$ a_1 \otimes a_2 = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i(u_i \otimes v_i)\\
b_1 \otimes b_2 = \sum_{j=1}^m c_i(w_j \otimes z_j)$$
where $a_i, c_i$ are scalars and $u_i \otimes v_i$, $w_i \otimes z_i$ are basis elements. And hence
$$\begin{align}
\langle a_1 \otimes a_2, b_1 \otimes b_2 \rangle &= \langle \sum_{i=1}^n a_i(u_i \otimes v_i), \sum_{i=1}^m c_j(w_j \otimes z_j) \rangle \\&= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_i\overline{c_j}\langle u_i \otimes v_i, w_j \otimes z_j \rangle \\&= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_i\overline{c_j}\langle u_i, w_j\rangle_1 \cdot \langle v_i,   z_j \rangle_2.
\end{align}$$

Assuming the above is even correct, it seems very cumbersome when decomposition into basis elements is not obvious, and that it may break down in the infinite dimensional case.

Is the above method correct, and if so is it the only way to take inner products for arbitrary vectors in the tensor product of a Hilbert space?